# Can anyone make a flowchart for proving prakshipt or answer these questions with 2-3 examples

Tags: puranas, identification-request, evidence, verse

How to decide prakshipt
Edited Question(as previous question was misunderstood/not giving exact response seeking for) :

***I expect answer with flowchart of question that I can ask myself to prove prakshipt like***

https://www.reddit.com/r/Cryptozoology/comments/112v8iw/a_flowchart_about_determining_whether_an_organism/?rdt=65459

Include following or related question in flowchart

Or answer these questions with examples of prakshipt

1. does it contradict holy vedas?
2. is it morally unacceptable (from view point of some or all)

A) on basis of something that was morally acceptable then but now

-people are misunderstanding leelas

-scripture is wrong when...

B) not morally acceptable then and now both

C) scripture verses on morality contradicts

3)a) same scripture contradicts the told fact/story.

b) Different scripture contradict the fact told.

4. date of scripture composition is close to modern times??
5. It contradicts science

A) authentic theories most scienctist agree on

B) doubtful theories like new theory may or may not be true

*You can add more questions and subquestions+subparts. This is my request for general answer of prakshipt. You can even change wordings of question but
I have given general idea of what I am seeking for?*

Comment: You can have anything as fundamental and consider the rest as interpolation. Usually, Upanishads, Bhagavad Gita and Brahma Sutras are considered fundamental words and rest as *prakshipt* only.

Comment: @User29449 due to think ghost exists according to bhagvad gita 9.25

Comment: It's **not** about *thought*. *Hinduism* is no *Buddhism*. You are supposed to believe in things here.

Comment: @User29449 but I can't believe ghost exist . What to do? 

Comment: How can you believe in gods and not ghosts in that format?

Comment: @User29449 because creation needs creator

Comment: If you provide sunlight to water or ice or air or soil, organisms can't be formed(so athiests are idiots )and there is no chemical reaction which can produce organism. So, nature can't be creator of humans. But parambrahm parmeshwar create humans, animals , plants ‍♂️

Comment: Where did you find *creation*-*creator* theory in Upanishads? It's like a creation children are 100% controlled by their parents. In fact, there are *ways* to create organisms like virus out of pure chemical reactions only (they are semi-living organisms).

Comment: @User29449 scientist is creator of virus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151130/discussion-between-hope-and-user-29449).

Comment: Proving prakshipta or interpolation is not a simple process. It is sometimes subjective. There is unlikely to be a simple flow chart. Its complicated.

Comment: @observer I think  most purans prakshipt like krishna in last word of bhagvad gita is called yogeshwar but in puran , it shows rasleela which is against brahmachary part of yog. Also read this brahmvaivat puran krishn janam khand ch 105 verse 60 to 63 गौओ का छेदन करो , दो लाख हिरनो को काटो......को मारो और इनसे चार गुणा अर्थात चालीस लाख मेढो का वध करो | पर्व के दिन इनकी बलि ग्रामदेवी को भक्तिपूर्वक देनी –

Comment: @observer https://aryasamajvserranthindus.wordpress.com/2015/12/02/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%82-%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AA/     By reading these articles I have even started to doubt mantra which I chant daily(vishnu divya naam, vishnu shastranaam and shifted to gayatri mantra. Like behavior of mine and athiest toward scripture (other than vedas) I. E. Zero devotion

Comment: That's why I am asking

Comment: In my experience, it requires lots and lots of investigation to decipher prakshipta. I do not have much knowledge about arya samaj and their teachings.

Comment: There is no completely objective way of proving prakshipta. The method used by the academicians though is to compare all the various existing manuscripts of a text and then discard the verses which are not present in majority of the manuscripts as interpolations.

Comment: @User29449Where did you find creation-creator theory in Upanishads?  उपसंहारदर्शनान्नेति चेन्न क्षीरवद्धि।।2.1.24।।https://sandeepa.in/2022/07/11/brahma-sutras-adhyasa-or-superimposition-chapter-2-section-1-slokas-1-slokas-37/

If one says that the Supreme Brahman without external help cannot be the cause of the world because an agent is always a collector and is seen collecting material, then one can categorically refute this as even milk can turn to curds without any help and from milk, so many things are produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be given this way

> brahmavaivat puran chapter 105
>
> गवां लक्षंछेदनं च हरिणानाँ द्विलक्षकम् |
>
> चतुर्लक्षं शशानाँ च कूर्माणां च तथा करु ||61||
>
> दशलक्षं छागलानाँ भेटाना तच्चतुर्गुणम् |
>
> पर्वणि ग्रामदेव्यै च बलिं देहि च भक्तितः ||62||
>
> एतेषाँ पक्वमाँसं च भोजनार्थ च कारय |
>
> परिपूर्ण व्यँजनानाँ सामग्री कुरु भूमिप ||63.
>
> One lakh cows were cut down and two lakh deer were cut down
>
> Do the same for four lakh rabbits and tortoises.  Meeting ten lakh
> goats is four times that   And offer sacrifice to the village goddess
> on the festival with devotion.
>
> Make these cooked meat and food

Now, if you know basics of hinduism then you will know cow is sacred and people should avoid non veg(tamsic food)

So, above verse is prakshipt

Now, come to other things.

Let's suppose a verse is claiming unscientific and false things then deny it.

Yoga vasistha 2.18

> verse 2 Even human compositions are acceptable when they are
> instructive of good sense; otherwise the Vedas also are to be
> renounced (as unreliable); because men are required always to abide by
> reason.
>
> verse 3 Words conformable with reason are to be received even if
> spoken by boys; otherwise they are to be rejected as straws though
> pronounced by the lotus-born (Brahma himself).

But don't apply this thing to idea of atma and parmatma because it is beyond human intellect

*Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 3, Verse 42
The senses are superior to the gross body, and superior to the senses is the mind. Beyond the mind is the intellect, and even beyond the intellect is the soul.*

If different scripture contradict a story

Then scripture which is historically before or initial must be given priority

If same scripture contradict the story then coming to conclusion is hard but whatever one's intellect feels right should be kept in mind.

Comment: The Answer isn't convincing. It simply asserts that whatever doesn't fit one's view of correct should be rejected as interpolation.

Comment: The reasoning given for the rejection of the Brahmavaivarta verses are flimsy and ignore the context completely. The text isn't actually endorsing meat eating and stuff it is simply depicting someone doing it in the course of the story. That someone happens to be Rukmi, who is himself depicted in the story as an Adhārmika personality

Answer (score -3):

> If someone don't think any prakshipt exist, then allopanishad is proof

Everything except Allah Upanishad is authentic, simple.

On a serious note though, to understand what goes against Veda, you have to understand Veda. To understand Veda, read Itihaasa and Puraana. If one portion of Purana is completely opposite to another section in Puraana or Itihaasa, then you try to understand that section in different ways. If in no way is it
in agreement with Veda, other Puranas and Itihaasas, then you can set it aside.

Pretty simple. It requires you to read, a LOT though.

Ghosts are real because many Puranas and Itihaasas refer to them.

Basically, read a lot, and keep what makes sense. If you're not able to put that much time or don't think you have that amount of mental capability, then follow a guru like Svami Avimukteshwarananda, Shankaracharya of Badarika Aashrama. He and others of similar position have done that work for you, so you can just follow what they say.

Anything you dislike or are uncomfortable with doesn't magically become an interpolation. UtaaraKaanda of Raamayana is authentic, horse sacrifice in Veda is authentic, (what appears like) beastiality with that horse is also authentic, discrimination based on Varna in DharmaShashtras is authentic, (what from a modern view looks like) oppression of women is also authentic. Shivalinga being the phallus of Shiva is also authentic. Child marriage is authentic. The attempted rape by Brahmaa of Saraswati is also authentic among many many other things. All these are authentic, unless you want to just throw away the whole thing altogether or do mental gymnastics like Arya Smaaj or neo Vedantins. Of course, most of these things do not have a malicious meaning that they appear to have, but you can't just throw out things because you don't like how it looks on the surface.

You can throw these things out, sure, but then you shouldn't attempt to call them interpolations, because they're not. Just say you follow your own cherry picked religion, like the Christians who support homosexuality despite what the Bible, old and new testament, says. Simply don't pretend to be traditional or authentic, and it's all good.

Comment: Yes Allopanishad is fake

Comment: https://aryasamajvserranthindus.wordpress.com/2015/12/02/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%82-%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AA/       means too many later additions if you read the page

Comment: @Hope 1The translation for the Daitya one is wrong, it talks about 6000 Daityas living in Bharata, in Satya Yuga (Mahabharata didn't even exist til start of Kali, remember?) 1 Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya is opinion of Madhavacharya, that's not valid, the source hasn't been provided either in terms of verses. 3The adhyaayas can be split up, or joined together to make things flow together, this is observed in all texts, it doesn't mean there's interpolation. As for missing verses, even the Veda has only less than 15 Shakhas out of 1100+, does that mean it's interpolated? No.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar so, in one chapter balram is avtar of vishnu and in other, he is avtar of vishnu. Also what about garud puran verse

Comment: @Hope I think you mistyped what you wanted to say, but I think your issue is Balraama being Sheshanaaga and Vishnu avataara at same time. Both are true. Just like your parent can be your father and your mother at the same time.

Garuda Purana verse is the Daitya one, which is wrongly translated.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar any proofs addhyas being merged up

Comment: @Hope  Sure, in Vanaparva, Chapter 75 of BORI CE is merged into Chapter 74 of Kumbhaghonam, making it have one less Adhyaaya (on the surface, anyways). Which means Adhyaaya 76 of BORI CE = Adhyaaya 75 of Kumbhaghonam.  Here are links, if you want to check: https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-03-sa.html
https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-03.pdf

This is very common, not just here, it's true in Puranas and even Ramayana. It has nothing to do with Interpolation, somethings just flow better by joining or separating, so people change it.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar can you check this verse. I think this proves brahmavaivat puran prakshipt ब्रह्मवैवर्त. कृष्ण जन्म अध्याय 105 के श्लोक 61 , 62 ,63-
श्लोक – गवां लक्षंछेदनं च हरिणानाँ द्विलक्षकम् | चतुर्लक्षं शशानाँ च कूर्माणां च तथा करु ||61|| दशलक्षं छागलानाँ भेटाना तच्चतुर्गुणम् | पर्वणि ग्रामदेव्यै च बलिं देहि च भक्तितः ||62|| एतेषाँ पक्वमाँसं च भोजनार्थ च कारय | परिपूर्ण व्यँजनानाँ सामग्री कुरु भूमिप ||63. 
                 एक लाख गौओ का छेदन करो , दो लाख हिरनो को काटो......को मारो और इनसे चार गुणा अर्थात चालीस लाख मेढो का वध करो | पर्व के दिन इनकी बलि ग्रामदेवी को भक्तिपूर्वक देनी

Comment: @Hope Killing cows is in Yajnavalkya Dharma Shastra, Aapastamba grhya sutra among others. It doesn't prove that there's any interpolation. It's also in the Veda (Gomedha Yajna and other references). For eg: Rig veda 10.91.14 14 “I offer graceful praise with all my heart to Agni, the drinker of water, whose back is sprinkled with Soma, the ordainer (of the rite), to whom vigorous horses and bulls and barren cows and sheep are consigned as burnt offerings.”

Unless you say that the Veda is also interpolated... the validity of the Puranas isn't discarded.

Comment: @Hope I'm saying this again, just because you don't like something or it doesn't fit your (false) conceptions of reality and morality and dharma doesn't make it interpolated. I haven't found a single credible instance of interpolation in Puranas/Itihaasa. Bhavishya Purana mention of Jesus/Muhammad is authentic (the author knew the future). Mention of Yavanas is authentic (Yavana doesn't JUST mean greek). Mention of Buddhism in Ramayana is authentic too (there's hundreds of previous buddhas and Tirthankaras, Jainism and Buddhism are both ancient). Feel free to bring up other possibilities .

Comment: Not to mention, THE most important point, why will someone go to the effort of putting his own childish understandings over the words of the Rshis and Devas? EVEN if one attempts this, SURELY the others around him would object or put a stop to it. The claim of this being done by Muslims and the British is also false. At best, they've produced faulty translations/interpretations (excluding clearly obvious exceptions like Allah Upanishad). Have some faith in the Paramparaa.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar पदार्थ

(यस्मिन्) जिस उपासना में लाये परमात्मा में अथवा जिसके आश्रय में (उक्षणः) सींचने में समर्थ (अश्वासः) घोड़े (ऋषभासः) वृषभ (वशाः) कमनीय दूध देनेवाली गौवें (मेषाः) ऊन देनेवाली भेड़ बकरियाँ (अवसृष्टासः) पर्याप्त (आहुताः) अभिप्राप्त (कीलालपे) उस अन्नरक्षक (सोमपृष्ठाय) सौम्य औषधीरस जैसा आनन्द स्पृष्ट किया है, आत्मा में भावित किया है जिसके आश्रय से, उस (वेधसे-अग्नये) उस विधाता परमात्मा के लिए (हृदा-चारुं मतिं जनये) हृदय से मन से अतिसुन्दर आस्तिक मति को मैं उत्पन्न करता हूँ

Comment: Meaning

With love and devotion at heart I create this song of thoughtful praise for the kind and gracious Agni under whose order and dispensation horses, virile bulls, cows, sheep and goats are created and range around freely and then are called back to the stalls.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar these are fake translation by british .check real https://vedicscriptures.in/rigveda/10/91/14

Comment: Don't do this because           manu 11.56 ब्रह्मोज्झता वेदनिन्दा कौटसाक्ष्यं सुहृद्वधः ।
गर्हितानाद्ययोर्जग्धिः सुरापानसमानि षट् ॥
Neglecting/Forgetting the Veda, reviling the Vedas, giving false evidence, slaying a friend, eating forbidden food, or (swallowing substances) unfit for food, are six (offences) equal to drinking Sura.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151228/discussion-between-dushyant-shreyaskar-and-hope).